# Azure Functions on .net6.0 fail to run locally with hostpolicy.dll error

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

One of our developers is currently building an Azure Function app in .Net 6.0 using Visual Studio 2022 Preview on Windows 10.

The solution has several projects, 1 Azure Function and several class libraries. It fails to run with:

> Metadata generation failed. Exit code: '-2147450750' Error: 'Failed to load the dll from [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.0.0\hostpolicy.dll], HRESULT: 0x800700C1An error occurred while loading required library hostpolicy.dll from [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.0.0]' DATA.Services.CompaniesQuery.Function C:\Users\r_ver.nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.webjobs.script.extensionsmetadatagenerator\4.0.1\build\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator.targets 37

Microsoft.NETCore.App is using version 6.0.1 and is listed until Solution Explorer in the Azure Function project in Dependencies > Frameworks > Microsoft.NETCore.App.

We have tried the following:

Reinstalling .Net 6 SDK

Reinstalled VS 2022 version 17.0.5

Laptop restart

Deleted contents of "C:\Users\someuser.nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.webjobs.script.extensionsmetadatagenerator" folder.

C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App has folder for .Net Core 2.0.0 and 6.0.1

The error relates to 2.0.0 however no references are made to this in the project including csproj files.

Is a manual update required to the targets file? Currently not aware of any resolution to this.

Comment: Have you installed the latest version of the Azure Functions Core Tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried in my environment and it works as expected,

To build an Azure Function app in `.Net 6.0` using `Visual Studio 2022` Preview(17.0.5) on Windows 10.

Below are the steps which i have followed:

- Installed latest version [***`Azure function core tools 4x`***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=v4%2Cwindows%2Ccsharp%2Cportal%2Cbash%2Ckeda#v2)
- Create an **Azure function** >**.net 6** > **ANONYMOUS**(*Authorization level*)> **Create**.

After that make sure that we have Azure function runtime v4 is available in `.csproj` file as below:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

[image]

- Allowed firewall setting

[image]

***OUTPUT:-***

[image]
[image]

***NOTE:-***

- When installing Azure function core tools version, make sure that we have installed only one core tool version on our computer.
- .net 6 supports Azure function runtime version 4x only.

For more information please refer this ***Microsoft Documentation***: [***Azure Functions runtime versions overview***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions?tabs=in-process%2Cv4&pivots=programming-language-csharp)

Comment: Thanks - I'll ask the developer to follow step-by-step then report back.

Comment: The actual fix was to delete the C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App  folder with all the 2.0 files in it. No idea why those were being referenced.

Comment: Yes that's correct sometimes we need to update `environment variable`  as well for this kind of error.

Comment: I'm going to mark your answer as solution anyway - it's a useful rehearsal of the necessary steps.

Comment: Sure @JudeFisher, Thank you:)