# Azure Finctions on .NET6 isolated fails to run locally with hostpolicy.dll

Tags: azure-functions, .net-6.0

I tried following answers: [Azure Functions on .net6.0 fail to run locally with hostpolicy.dll error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70745114/azure-functions-on-net6-0-fail-to-run-locally-with-hostpolicy-dll-error/70751225). And a .NET6 function will run but when I make a .NET6 isolated project and try to run I still get following error.

```
Failed to load the dll from [C:\Users\mnir\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.10.1\cli_x64\hostpolicy.dll], HRESULT: 0x800700C1
An error occurred while loading required library hostpolicy.dll from [C:\Users\mnir\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.10.1\cli_x64\]
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the workarounds is to swap the Environment variables paths of dotnet 32-bit and 64-bit versions i.e..

[image]

For more information you can refer [Failed to load the dll](https://brettmckenzie.net/2021/11/11/failed-to-load-the-dll-from-localappdataazurefunctionstoolsreleases3-30-1cli_x64hostpolicy-dll-hresult-0x800700c1/)

Comment: I swapped them but didn't change anything for me..

Comment: @MounirMehjoub Can you please try restarting your system and try again

Comment: I tried didn't help